# Generating repeated elements in a list

Tags: list-manipulation

Is there a function in mathematica that allows you to generate repeated elements inline within a list. For example, let's say you provided this as input text:

> {1, 2, 3, 4, Repeat[5,3], 6, 7}

Then I would want Mathematica to provide the output as

> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7}

I know there already exists something similar `ConstantArray` and `Nest` but they cannot be used in the manner described above, for doing so leads to a nested list:

> {1, 2, 3, 4, ConstantArray[5, 3], 6}
>
> {1, 2, 3, 4, {5, 5, 5}, 6}

which I would then have to Flatten, a clunky solution that is less elegant than ideal.

Since I am reasonably sure that no native function exists, how would you go about building one?

Comment: You are looking for `Sequence`! Alternatively, if you really want to build it yourself, `Replace` with a suitable pattern will do the job.

Comment: `Sequence@ConstantArray...`

Comment: @ciao `Sequence@@ConstantArray[..]` -- you have a typo.

Comment: @OleksandrR. Can you show a usage example? I don't see how to use sequence when trying to splice in repeated copies of an element.

Comment: Of course. `{1, Sequence @@ ConstantArray[5, 3], 2}` gives `{1, 5, 5, 5, 2}`. Define `repeat[what_, times_] := Sequence @@ ConstantArray[what, times]` and you can write `{1, 2, 3, 4, repeat[5,3], 6, 7}`, just like in the question.

Comment: @OleksandrR. Friggin' autocorrect...

Comment: PadLeft or PadRight can help

Comment: I believe `Table` is exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can write your own repeat function like this:

```
repeat[m_, n_Integer?Positive] := Sequence @@ ConstantArray[m, n]
```

Then

```
{1, 2, 3, 4, repeat[5, 3], 6, 7}
```

evaluates to

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7}
> ```

The first argument can be anything.

```
{1, 2, 3, 4, repeat["anything", 2], 6, 7}
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, 4, "anything", "anything", 6, 7}
> ```

Comment: I told my doctor, "When I do this it hurts". He told me, "Then don't do that". :P