# How to transform an arithmetico-geometric progression into a flattened list?

Tags: list-manipulation

Suppose I have a list like

```
L1 = {a,2b,3c,...}
```

I want to transform it to a list of the form

```
 L2 = {a, b, b, c, c, c, ...}
```

How do I do that?

Comment: closely related: [**92728**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/92728/5478), [**111863**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/111863/5478), [**56839**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56839/5478)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So our `L1` is actually a list of things with format `Times[__]`:

```
In[88]:= L1 = Range[26]*ToExpression@Alphabet[]

Out[88]= {a, 2 b, 3 c, 4 d, 5 e, 6 f, 7 g, 8 h, 9 i, 10 j, 11 k, 12 l,
  13 m, 14 n, 15 o, 16 p, 17 q, 18 r, 19 s, 20 t, 21 u, 22 v, 23 w, 
 24 x, 25 y, 26 z}

In[97]:= L1[[13]] // FullForm

Out[97]:= Times[13,m]
```

Which means we can use this in `ReplaceAll`:

```
L1 /. Times[n_Integer, s_] :> ConstantArray[s, n] // Flatten
```

The `Flatten` call there simply takes the nested lists and flattens them all out.

Answer (score 6):

```
## & @@ ConstantArray[#2, #] & @@@ L1
```

Alternatively:

```
Replace[
 L1,
 sym_Symbol n_. :> Sequence @@ ConstantArray[sym, n],
 {1}
]
```

Comment: Thank you. Both answers more or less give the same method.