# How to manipulate two list?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two lists,

```
A = {400,500,600,......}
```

and

```
B = {1,2,3,....}
```

How to get a new list of the form ?

```
C = {400, 500,500,600,600,600,......}
```

Comment: also related: [**139996**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/139996/5478),  [**92728**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/92728/5478),  [**56839**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56839/5478)

Comment: I think it is an exact duplicate but let me know if you disagree with closing.

Comment: Thank you I got it.  It is exactly similar to  56839.

Comment: I meant http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/111863/replicate-sublist-in-new-list

Comment: Yes, Thank you.